# Log out or sign out of Apple's Bug Reporter AKA Radar?

Tags: bug, developer-program

I accidentally signed into Radar with the wrong account and I can't find the log out or sign out button in order to switch accounts. Is there any alternative besides clearing my cache?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nm, I found it after clicking around. You have to click on the tiny padlock to sign out.

[image]